# preg_match_all empty matches

Tags: php, regex

I want to match any letter and an underscore between two dollar signs and get the matches as result.

Example:

I get `<a href="$url$">foo</a>` and I want to have `url` or `$url$`

I've tried the following two patterns

```
$pattern = "/\$([a-z\_]*)\$/i";
$pattern = "/\$(.*)\$/i"; // well, that's actually not what I want.
preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Okay this should work - at least it does on [regex101](https://regex101.com/). But it doesn't when I test it within my app. I just get empty test results

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } } 
// ...
```

Any ideas?

Here is a sample text I use to test it (I test it per line)

```
<li>
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="$application_url$">
            <img preview_image src="$thumbnail$">
            <div class="battle_tag">$btag$</div>
            <div class="class_spec">$spec_one$  /  $spec_two$ $class$</div>
            <div class="item_lvl">ilvl $ilvl$</div>
            <div class="date">$obtained$</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Well since I'm not very familiar with PHP I'll post the code how I read get the actual strings too. Maybe I'm already doin something wrong here.

```
$file = file($filename);

for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++){
    $line = $file[$i];
    preg_match_all("/\$([a-z]*)\$/i", $line, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem lies with your Regex, i tested it out here http://www.rubular.com/r/Zn0KDz2IyU

Comment: @Upio I feared this too. But to be honest I've no idea what could be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes around your regex:

```
preg_match_all( '/\$([a-z_]*)\$/i', $line, $matches );
```

[Single quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) take PHP out of [*variable interpolation*](https://phppot.com/php/variable-interpolation-in-php/) mode. Typically escaping the `\$` within a double quoted string is enough, but apparently not when that double quoted string is a regular expression.